# How to retrieve arrays from FirebaseFirestore using Collections?

Tags: java, android, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[This is my Firestore database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iqstj.jpg)

```
db.collection("PublicFormDetails")
                .whereEqualTo("Topic Name",message)
                .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshot : Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult())) {
                        String value1 = snapshot.getString("QuestionName");
                        Toast.makeText(PublicVote.this, value1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        q_tv1.setText("Question: "+value1);
                    }
                }
                }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(PublicVote.this,e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Now here I want to retrieve **Description and No. of Options** which is saved in the form of an array, my code above prints other details of the data as well, with respect to the topic name selected hence I've used whereEqualTo("Topic Name", message)as my query(where the message is the topic I select).
How to retrieve Description and No. of Options now in this. I can't use DocumentReference because then I won't be able to use whereEqualsTo. Please help!!!

Comment: you can also use the modal class. see this doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the content of those two araays, please add the following two lines of code inside the for loop:

```
List<String> description = (List<String>) snapshot.get("Description");
List<String> noOfOptions = (List<String>) snapshot.get("Np. of Options");
```

Right after this line:

```
q_tv1.setText("Question: "+value1);
```

If you need each element within those arrays, create a for loop for each list and get the corresponding data.

The result in the logcat will be:

```
Hey
What's up?
```

For the first array, and:

```
123
456
```

For the second array.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! @AlexMamo It comes as cannot resolve symbol document. I'm using QuerySnapshot right so document won't work I guess.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Please see my updated answer. Should be `snapshot` instead of `document`. Does it work now?

Comment: Good to hear that it worked. You're very welcome.